# How to dynamically update 3 dimensional Array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a 3d array-DataSeriesToPlot in Javascript, what I want to do is all first half rows' elements value plus a value- scale, all remaining half rows'elements value minus the value-scale. The code is like the below showed,

```
for ( var i = 0; i < DataSeriesToPlot.length; i++) {
    for ( var j = 0; j < DataSeriesToPlot[i].length; j++) {
        if ((i >= 0) && (i < (DataSeriesToPlot.length / 2))) {

            DataSeriesToPlot[i][j][1] = (parseFloat(DataSeriesToPlot[i][j][1]) + parseFloat(scale))
                    .toFixed(2);
        } else {
            DataSeriesToPlot[i][j][1] = (parseFloat(DataSeriesToPlot[i][j][1]) - parseFloat(scale))
                    .toFixed(2);
        }

for ( var j = 0; j < DataSeriesToPlot.length; j++) {
console.log("aaaaa"+DataSeriesToPlot[j]);



            }
```

But this ways seems incorrect, because the console output the original value of this 3d array, all values haven't been changed. Could you please help me figure out where the error is? Thanks!

Comment: could you provide us the sample array, you've used?

Comment: With testing data like `var DataSeriesToPlot = [[[0,1], [0,2], [0,3]], [[0,4], [0,5], [0,6]]], scale = 2;` I don't see any problem.

Comment: Thanks! All. I think is my 3d Array format issue.Thanks!